# GRAVE: Error listenerStart

Tags: spring, tomcat

i'm having this error when i try to run my application i don't know why...

> GRAVE: Error listenerStart 11 sept. 2011 23:37:04 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal GRAVE:Error Starting context [/ gest_project] following previous errors

here is my web xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <!--Upload Filters-->
    <filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
<!--End Upload Filters-->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Theme Aristo -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>start</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!--       FIN         -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/admin-direction.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
   <!-- Add Support for Spring -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

   <!-- JSF mapping -->


  <!-- Map these files with JSF -->

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

here is the hole log:

```
12 sept. 2011 14:30:24 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event of (context initialized) to the class instance to listen (listener)
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [gest_project.model.metier.ActeurServiceImp] for bean with name 'acteurService' defined in file [C:\Users\nadya\Documents\NetBeansProjects\gest_project\target\gest_project\WEB-INF\classes\gest_project\model\metier\ActeurServiceImp.class]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gest_project/model/metier/ActeurService
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1144)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1177)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:758)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:422)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4681)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5184)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5179)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gest_project/model/metier/ActeurService
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2818)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1148)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1643)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:211)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:385)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1138)
... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gest_project.model.metier.ActeurService
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
... 28 more
12 sept. 2011 14:30:26 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

regards.

Comment: Can you show stacktraces of that previous errors?

Comment: @axtavt i added tomcat log, but i think the previous error referred  to is:
GRAVE: Error listenerStart 11 sept. 2011 23:37:04 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a class `gest_project.model.metier.ActeurServiceImp`, which I'm guessing uses a `@Service` or maybe `@Component` annotation to make it a Spring bean, and it looks like it implements an interface named `gest_project.model.metier.ActeurService`. That interface isn't available to your app, hence the NoClassDefFoundError.